# How can i use partials in dustjs with expressjs when all my templates are remotely placed

Tags: node.js, express, template-engine, dust.js

All my Dustjs templates are kept precompiled in a database. To render the template I have this function

```
tmplfn(options, function (err, html) {
    res.write(html);  //res is the response object
    res.end();
});
```

But this fails when the templates have got partials in it because it is not able to locate the partial.  How can I resolve this issue? Is there any mechanism to register my partial with the dustengine?

Comment: Relevant to crimson.js, consider revising.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with dust.js myself, but according to [the docs](http://akdubya.github.io/dustjs/):

> ```
> dust.onLoad(name, callback(err, out))
> ```
>
> By default Dust returns a "template not found" error when a named template cannot be located in the cache. Override `onLoad` to specify a fallback loading mechanism (e.g., to load templates from the filesystem or a database).

This seems to me like a good starting point.